# How to click on Button hiding inside my text box in the form of image at the corner for appium

Tags: appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

How to click on Button hiding inside my text box in the form of image at the corner for Appium mobile testing

I need to click on the image. If I click on that image, it will display
one popup and i am unable to find locator separately for the image using 
UIAUTOMATOR VIEWER because image is inside my textbox so please help me 
to overcome from this i am not able to  proceed.

I am using UIautomator viewer tool avalible to find the locator more unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TouchAction](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidTouchTest.java) and click by coordinates:

```
WebElement accountTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("account_edit_text"));
Point point = accountTextBox.getLocation();
int shiftX = accountTextBox.getSize().width - 5; // you can adjust it
int shiftY = accountTextBox.getSize().height/2;
new TouchAction(driver)
  .press(point.x + shiftX, point.y + shiftY)
  .waitAction(ofSeconds(1))
  .release()
  .perform();
```

Also you can use [Appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) and try `automationName` capability set to `UIAutomator2` and check what XML its gonna build: it might parse button as separate element.

Comment: Hi i tried with coordinates but it change for every device so when i tested in one device its works but when i change the device it doesn't work.

code used is

TouchAction tapCoordinates = new TouchAction(driver); //where driver is AppiumDriver tapCoordinates.tap(1324,609).perform();

TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction(driver); touchAction.tap(1500, 700).perform();

can u please suggest some other way to tap at the flag image please see the attached image in question section. because i am stuck in login section. please help me to come out of the step

Comment: Do you see the difference between your code and mine? I do. Don't try to tap by abstract coordinates, but find the account_edit_text element, get it coordinates (they will differ from device to device, so thats why I search for element, not hardcode coordinates). And I'm pretty sure that flag icon is 5- 15 px shifted from right border of textbox, so just measure it on several devices and thats it. Give a try to my code, I didn't post it just to complain :)

Comment: Sorry Sir your code work perfect by just copy and paste in my code..               can u please explain the above code..and also where this id comes from driver.findElement(By.id("account_edit_text")); thanks in advance.